# Transparent Header with App Framework

Tags: html, css, cordova, intel-xdk, appframework

I'm trying to use the appframework with intel XDK to make a transparent header however when I style the main div in which the app is contained to have a background I get a sliver of whitespace above it, what should I style so that when  I set a header to `background-color: transparent !important`the background color holds? My guess is this is a specific appframework question but it may also be a generic html thing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
header {background-color: transparent !important}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that's what I'm using in the screenshot above. even if the header is transparent the background doesn't go to the top of the screen.